# Static analysis of actors in Scala

Tags: scala, actor, static-analysis

I am searching for Papers and programs for the static analysis of actors in Scala. Is there any program which allows the static detection of message passing errors in Scala (using Akka Actors)?

I've only found the Paper "Detection of Asynchronous Message Passing Errors Using Static Analysis" by Christakis and Sagonas about the analysis of message passing errors in Erlang. They wrote another Paper called "Static Detection of Deadlocks in Erlang". I've not yet found any source code by them which they contributed to the dialyzer but I think the same methods should work with Scala too.